# Function: Finding Col names from a DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, function, syntax

This is the error I am getting:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I am attempting to pass the variable dataname to the function Colnames so that it will return the names of the columns for the respective dataframe. I want to display an error message on invalid user input but the I am screwing up the syntax. I think the logic should be okay? I have tried the If statement with and without the parentheses

```
def Colnames(dataname):
If (dataname == 'df1'):
    data_cols = df1.columns
Elif (dataname == 'df2'):
    data_cols = df2.columns
Else:
   tk.messagebox.showerror('Error: User Input. Please Enter df1 or df2')
return print(data_cols)
```

Should return column names of df1 with Colnames(df1).

If you have any thoughts please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some indentation and casing issues there - this should work:

```
def Colnames(dataname):
    if (dataname == 'df1'):
        data_cols = df1.columns
    elif (dataname == 'df2'):
        data_cols = df2.columns
    else:
        tk.messagebox.showerror('Error: User Input. Please Enter df1 or df2')
    return data_cols
```

Comment: Thank you! I also wanted a way to get rid of the index format when it displays the col names. My answer below seemed to take care of this. I also ditched the tkinter messagebox just bc.

Answer (score 0):

```
def Colnames(dataname):
    if dataname == 'df1':
        data_cols = df1.columns
        for i in data_cols: 
            print(i)
    elif dataname == 'df2':
        data_cols = df2.columns
        for i in data_cols: 
            print(i)
    else:
        print('Error: User Input. Please Enter df1 or df2')
    return
Colnames('df1')
```